# For which values ${(a,1,0),(1,a,1), (0,1,a)}$ form a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

To the set be a basis we should have:

$$x(a,1,0)+y(1,a,1)+z(0,1,a) = (0,0,0)\implies x=y=z=0$$ so:

$$ax + y = 0\\x + ay + z = 0\\y + az = 0$$

which is a system that only has a unique solution if the determinant of its matrix is not $0$, so:

$$\mbox{det} \begin{bmatrix}a & 1 & 0\\1 & a & 1 \\0 & 1 & a\end{bmatrix}\neq 0$$

this determinant gives $a^3 -2a \neq 0\implies a(a^2-2)\neq 0 \implies a\neq 0, a\neq \pm \sqrt{2}$ but my book says the answer is:

$$a\neq 0, a\neq \pm 1$$

Comment: You are right, the book is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct. You can check e.g. that $a \neq 1$ cannot be part of the answer since, substituting $a = 1$ in the matrix, a row reduction would give $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\\0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ and this matrix has determinant $-1$.